# Telling scatter3D from plot3D library to plot the tick labels

Tags: r, 3d, label, scatter-plot, plot3d

I am doing a 3D scatter plot using the scatter3D function of the plot3D library but I can not find the way to give the syntax so that the plot contains the tick labels.

My code is the following:

```
library(plot3D)
A <- c(0, 1, 0, 1)
B <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
y <- c(52, 74, 62, 80)
scatter3D(x = A, y = B, z = y,  col = "red", phi = 0, cex = 2, bty = "g", alpha = 0.5 , pch = 20, nticks = 10,
          xlab = "Time Factor", ylab = "Corn Factor", zlab = "Outcome", main = "Experiment with 2 Factors")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/2.1-5/topics/scatter3d), there is a mention of the argument:

```
...    arguments to be passed down
```

These are passed down to [persp](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/persp.html). There it is stated that ticktype is defaulted to 'simple', but can be altered to 'detailed'. So adding the argument

```
ticktype= "detailed"
```

should work. Hope this helps!